# Add 1 container in 2 Panels

Tags: extjs, containers, panel

Is it possible to add one container in two different panels? I tried doing something like this

```
var container =  Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
    //container content
});

var panel1 = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    //panel1 content
    items : [container]
});

var panel2 = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    //panel2 content
    items : [container]
});
```

But it adds the container only in the second Panel

Here is a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1v2m)

Comment: This small code looks correct.But can you show same thing on fiddle, I can check there.

Comment: @Tejas1991: This is the [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1v2m) for the program im trying to make. As you can see the container is added only to the second panel

Comment: I just debugged your issue and fixed it will it post it as answer in few mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a little bit on your use case. 
If you feel fine rendering the container two times you can just pass the config of the container to your panels:

```
var container = {
    //container content
    items: {
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        value: 'container content'
    }
};

var panel1 = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    //panel1 content
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'panel1',
    items: container
});

var panel2 = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    //panel2 content
     renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'panel2',
    items: container
});
```

For reusing the instance and placing the same instance two times on different positions in the dom i see no way of achieving that. I even think its not doable at all, but maybe someone else can teach me how to do it in a clean and cozy way ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var container = {

    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text : 'select',
         handler: function() {
            alert(this.up('form').getTitle()+ " clicked");
        }
    }]
};

var panel1 = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    //panel1 content
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'panel1',
    items: container
});

var panel2 = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    //panel2 content
     renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    title: 'panel2',
    items: container
});
```

container is rendered on both panels.